# How can I rerender resources when state of Admin component is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I get resources dynamicaly by function. When I change screen-size, I want again run this function. I thought I can add state "screenSize"in admin-component and by resize change state, but when I change state, resources don't render again.

```
<Admin
      customReducers={customReducers}
      dashboard={Dashboard}
      restClient={restClient}
      loginPage={CustomLoginPage}
      authClient={authClient}
      menu={CustomMenu}
      screenSize="medium"
    >
      //we get thisby auth_get_permissions in authClient
      {({ modules}) => loadingResources(modules)}
</Admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very efficient to rerender all resources when a screenSize changes, please use the `Responsive` component. That said, you can create a customLayout and pass it using the `appLayout` prop of `Admin`  and  force an update on that when the screensize prop changes.